# My JavaScript function doesn't see Global Variable (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

(Disclaimer: I'm a real novice to JS, don't get angry)
I have this piece of code:

```
var myUrl="getjson.php";


window.onload = function () {
    poll();
};

function poll() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: myURL,
            success: function (data) {

                //MyNamespace.myFunction(data); //DO ANY PROCESS HERE

            },
            complete: poll
        }); 
    }, 5000);
};
```

When trying to run it, the console reports "`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myURL (anonymous function)"`
What should I change to make this work, and why?

thanks ahead,

S

Comment: Javascript is a case-sensitive language. `myUrl` is not the same variable as `myURL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable name is different, its not `myURL`, its `myUrl`

Answer (score -2):

myURL is not the same as myUrl. Javascript is case sensitive.